Calculating max elevation of centroids in QGIS
How do I find the max elevation of the source area of landslide in QGIS?
I have polygons for the entire landslide and a separate polygon marked for source area where I'm interested in the max elevation of the centroid.

Can you add a screenshot? Do you have elevation data, for example a raster DEM?

If you mean the max elevation inside of the polygons that determine the source area and the slide, then try the Zonal Statistics Plugin.  As with most tools that use raster and vector data you should ensure that both data use the same coordinate reference system.
Also, I would encourage you to investigate the vertical datum of your surface models so that any comparisons you might make with other surface models are all using in the same datum.

Yes, it is inside of the polygons. But it is not possible to run Zonal Statistics since it is vector.

Oh, it looks like you need to scour the internet for some surface model data for your area of interest.  USA users have access to free 3DEP data and likely a repository for LiDAR data depending on your state.  https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/
